# Docker search command always lists empty result

Tags: docker, ubuntu-16.04

didn't find somebody with the same issue. I'm using ubuntu 16 xenial.
After installation of docker all were working fine. But today I tried to search some images and got empty results, doesn't matter what i'm typing:

```
> docker search lemp
NAME      DESCRIPTION   STARS     OFFICIAL   AUTOMATED
> docker search php
NAME      DESCRIPTION   STARS     OFFICIAL   AUTOMATED
> docker search mysql
NAME      DESCRIPTION   STARS     OFFICIAL   AUTOMATED
```

I already tried to reinstall it deleting all the files

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge docker-engine
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker
```

After reinstall getting the same problem.
I have no ideas, could it be firewall or something else, what should i check first, can u help me please.

Answer (score 0):

This must be a problem on the Docker Hub side, since if you try to enter any of those search terms into the search box at https://hub.docker.com/explore/, you also currently get zero results.

Comment: Yes, this maybe on their side. Images still can be downloaded using pull but should know the direct link